# batch file for executing sql query in a production server

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file, command

is it possible to create a batch file which run from local computer to execute a query in production server, production server can be accessible only through remote connection. ? if not possible please suggest some ways,

Requirement: Need a batch files to get query results from production server?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

Step-1:

Enter the below five lines and Save this as execute.bat file

---

```
set /P TargetServer=Enter Target DB Server IP:
set /P TargetDb=Enter Target DB Name:
set /P UserName=Enter UserName: 
set /P Passwd=Enter Password:
sqlcmd -S %TargetServer% -U %UserName% -P %Passwd% -d %TargetDb% -i MyScript.sql -o MyOutput.txt
```

---

Step-2

Provide your sqls in this file and save it as MyScript.sql

---

```
select *from tablename
```

---

Step-3

Place execute.bat and Myscript.sql files in a folder then double click the execute.bat file. Your output of the MyScript.sql is saved in MyOutput.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Batch file  and Keep it production server itself by scheduling a task Task Scheduler (Windows assumed OS). So that no need of Remote access to Production server every time.

This is my suggestion from what I understood from your question.

Comment: thanks for your comments my concern is how can we change the scripts, if user needs to get details for Different scripts, since drives in production server only accesible through remote connection